# Can a point be in the future without being "of time"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, formal-language

I wrote the following.

> We will revise it at some **point** in the future.

It's obvious, unambiguous and grammatically correct. However, I can't shake off the sensation that it's nonsensical because *a point* is a concept relating to spatial coordinates. Is it proper to metaphorically refer to a future occasion that way? Or should I use the version below?

> We will revise it at some **point of time** in the future.

One could argue that *revise at a point in the future* could be interpreted as revision being performed in a certain location (i.e. a point in space) and that such will occur in an unknown amount of time (i.e. in the future).

Is the above a correct interpretation? Is it the only correct interpretation?

Comment: **Spatial** co-ordinates.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Corrected. You have my *spacial* appreciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may safely dismiss from your mind the notion that to speak of 'a point in the future (or past)' is nonsensical. The interpretation that, in ordinary language (e.g. outside a physics department) the word 'point' used alone cannot apply to a moment or brief period of time, **is mistaken**. We can use the preposition 'in' however, but this is a matter of choice, and is not usually necessary for complete understanding, unless, maybe, both time and space are being discussed together.

> Point   3   COUNTABLE a particular moment in time
>
> at this/that point: *At that point we all got up and walked out of the
> room.*
>
> at this/that point in time: *At this point in time we can’t afford to
> hire any more people.*

[Point (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/point_1)